# Add a text field to OpenAM XUI login page

Tags: javascript, authentication, captcha, openam

I'm working on OpenAM 13.0 to add some features to meet my requirements of my customer.

I would like to add CAPTCHA to XUI login page and as the first step I've been trying to add a text field to the login page. At first, I tried to customize login.jsp in config folder and according to instructions cloned the default folder and added some elements to login.jsp in my realm config files. But, I couldn't see any effect.

Then I tried using Scripted Module to add Client Side Scripts. However, when I created a new script to add a text field, User Name and Password fields disappeared from login page.

My script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  fs = $(document.forms[0]).find("fieldset");
  var strUI='<div class="group-field-block"><label class="short">CAPTCHA:</label><input type="text" name="Captcha"/></div>';
  $(fs).append(strUI);
});
```

What's wrong in my JavaScript? What's the best practice to add some input fields to login page?

By the way, I can't use Google Recaptcha because I'm going to use OpenAM in a local intranet without Internet access.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to customize the XUI interface, you shouldn't be looking at the JSP files. The XUI is based on static HTML files and JavaScript, so the customization will need to be done differently. Considering that you are trying to add a new input field to the login page, actually, you need to customize an authentication module.

Each authentication module has their predetermined list of "callbacks" they can work with, and each callback represents some sort of an "input" for the authentication module. In order to add a new input field to the login screen you not just have to update the authentication module's callback descriptor XML (LDAP.xml for example in config/auth/default folder), but you would also need to update the authentication module itself so that it actually knows what to do with this new input value.

Comment: We recently found out that we can't buy OpenAM license and support because ForgeRock doesn't sell products to Iran. So, I had to stop working on OpenAM and move to something else. Thank you for the answer anyway.